# Flex - make parent width of children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex box layout. I want the width of `.outer-2` to be the width of its children, with `.outer-1` and `outer-3` taking up the rest of the space.

How can I achieve this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8tgyvbd/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.outer-1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}

.outer-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.outer-3 {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}

.inner {
  flex-basis: 30px;
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer-1">
  </div>
  <div class="outer-2">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it what you wants? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/v8tgyvbd/1/)

Comment: Muhammad Usman - almost, although in your example flex basis has no effect.

Comment: Is using CSS grids an option? This layout might be easier with that.

Comment: Two steps: (1) remove `flex: 1` from `.outer-2`. Telling the middle item to share equal width with its siblings is counter to your objective. (2) replace `flex-basis: 30px` with `width: 30px`. `flex-basis` isn't working as expected in this case. Not sure why. Maybe a bug. https://jsfiddle.net/v8tgyvbd/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the flex properties for the second child of `container` preventing it from growing to fit it's parent. That, and adding a width or min-width to each `.inner` element will prevent their parent from collapsing them down.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.outer-1{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}
.outer-2{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.outer-3{
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}
.inner{
  width: 30px;
  flex: 1 0 30px;
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer-1">
  
  </div>
  <div class="outer-2">
      <div class="inner">
  
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
  
      </div>
      <div class="inner">
  
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-3">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't use flex, your setting min-width.

Comment: Could you explain what you expect the `.inner` elements to do?

Comment: I want to set the width of the inner elements to be 30px using flex basis. The width of outer-2 should amount to the width of it's children.

Comment: Check my edit - is this accurate? Without setting width or min-width on the inner children, outer-2 is going to collapse them down.

Comment: Well I guess setting width is the only way!